# How to group an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I group this array by houseid ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1111
            [houseid] => 58
            [price] => 2995
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1112
            [houseid] => 58
            [price] => 4050
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1114
            [houseid] => 60
            [price] => 1695
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1115
            [houseid] => 60
            [price] => 2250
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1116
            [houseid] => 60
            [price] => 2295
        )
)
```

i need to calculate the total price for a houseid and do some math/conditions, it would be easy if the group this array...

can i format this array to something like

```
Array
(
    [58] => stdClass Object(
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1111
            [price] => 2995
        )
        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1112
            [houseid] => 58
            [price] => 4050
        )
    )
    [60] => stdClass Object(
        [0] => stdClass Object(
            [id] => 1114
            [price] => 1695
        )
        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1115
            [price] => 2250
        )
        [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1116
            [price] => 2295
        )
)
```

Or else can anyone suggest me, how to loop the original array to count the total price for a house ?

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com). There are plenty of similar Q&A regarding this.

Comment: i need to get houseids between some dates and got this array from a sql statement...and i need to reformat it to the need

Comment: that are lots of array function out their at least you are supposed to check them before asking question which shows no efforts

Comment: i spent almost 2hrs on this googling, checking php notes and all...it all depends on the situation you are in guys...when you've deadlines on your head, sometime very easy tasks also seems difficult...sincerely i never knew about array_reduce

Comment: @luvboy Looking at documentation typically helps me as it shows all the possible `array_` functions right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$data = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
    $id = $b->houseid;
    unset($b->houseid);
    $a[$id][] = $b;
    return $a;
});

var_dump($data);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  58 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[1]
          public 'id' => int 1111
          public 'price' => int 2995
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'id' => int 1112
          public 'price' => int 4050
  60 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'id' => int 1114
          public 'price' => int 1695
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'id' => int 1115
          public 'price' => int 2250
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'id' => int 1116
          public 'price' => int 2295
```

[Full live Demo](http://eval.in/3977)

Comment: OMG, i never knew about array_reduce, thanks a lot Baba...